# I can not install snap (snapd) in arch-linux

Tags: arch-linux, snap

I have the cloned git repository and that's where I run the command.
When I try to install snap I get the following error:

```
$ makepkg -s                                                                                       
 ==> Creando el paquete: snapd 2.39.3-1 (Tue 09 Jul 2019 12:09:44 PM -03)
 ==> Comprobando dependencias mientras se ejecuta...
 ==> Comprobando dependencias mientras se compila...
 ==> Recibiendo las fuentes...
  -> snapd-2.39.3.tar.xz ha sido encontrado 
 ==> Validando los archivos source con sha256sums...
snapd-2.39.3.tar.xz ... Aprobado
 ==> Extrayendo las fuentes...
  -> Extrayendo snapd-2.39.3.tar.xz con bsdtar
 ==> Iniciando prepare()...
 ==> Eliminando el directorio $pkgdir/...
 ==> Iniciando build()...
*** Setting version to '2.39.3-1' from shell.
# pkg-config --cflags  -- libseccomp libseccomp
Package libseccomp was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libseccomp.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libseccomp' found
Package libseccomp was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libseccomp.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libseccomp' found pkg-config: exit status 1
==> ERROR: Se produjo un fallo en build().
Cancelando...
```

I have tried to manually install libseccomp with the command:

`pacman -S libseccomp` 
and it does not work either. I have already commented on this problem on the package page but I have not yet achieved a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You left off the final option:

> -i, --install
>     Install or upgrade the package after a successful build using [pacman(8)](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/core/pacman/pacman.8.en)

On Arch Linux, snap can be installed from the [Arch User Repository (AUR)](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/snapd/).

The [manual build process](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository#Installing_packages) is the Arch-supported install method for AUR packages, and you’ll need the [prerequisites](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository#Prerequisites) installed before you can install any AUR package. You can then install snap with the following:

Clone the repository from the GitHub website.

```
$ git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/snapd.git
```

As soon as it downloads, change into the **snapd** directory.

```
$ cd snapd
```

From within the **snapd** directory execute the following command:

```
$ makepkg -si
```

Once installed, the [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd) [unit](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/systemd.unit.5) that manages the main snap communication socket needs to be enabled:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
```

To enable classic snap support, enter the following to create a symbolic link between /var/lib/snapd/snap and /snap:

```
$ sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
```

Either log out and back in again, or restart your system, to ensure snap’s paths are updated correctly.

To test your system, install the [hello-world](https://snapcraft.io/hello-world) snap and make sure it runs correctly:

Enter this into your terminal:

```
$ sudo snap install hello-world
```

This will return a message saying:

```
 hello-world 6.3 from Canonical✓ installed
```

Now all that's left is to execute the final command:

```
$ hello-world
```

If everything was installed correctly you will see this printed on your screen:

```
Hello World!
```

Snap is now installed and ready to go! If you’re using a desktop, you might want to install the [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-store-app) app.

All of this and more can be found at [Snapcraft.io](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-arch-linux/)